# Как перед назначением обработчика события сделать removeEventListener?

Tags: javascript, события

Как перед назначением обработчика события сделать removeEventListener?

То есть в итоге нужно просто затирать обработчик при последующем назначении.

На блоке `test` только один должен быть обработчик `click`, из примера это третий вызов `union()`

Ниже короткий условный пример

```js
function union() {
  document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('click');
  });
}

union();
union();
union();
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Comment: вынеси обработчик в функцию и удаляй

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто используйте [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#notes) для этой задачи:

```js
function union() {
document.querySelector('.test').onclick = (e) => {
    console.log('click');
  };
}

union();
union();
union();
```

```html
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! я и забыл про такое свойство, привык всегда через метод делать)

Comment: @Meru382: ну, Grundy тоже прав - если нужен именно removeEventListener, то нужно ему скармливать имя функции.

Comment: @UModeL, не, не имя, а ту же самую функцию

Comment: @Grundy: упростил ;-)